# codeigniter upload image with other data

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form am submitting and user has the ability to upload a picture in that form then submit the form as whole. I found a tutorial on codeigniter site showing upload form (dedicated only to upload, not other data along). link is: [Codeigniter Upload Tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html). How can I submit the form and then upload the files while also uploading other details to other table in database?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example

```
    function add_staff(){
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            // field name, error message, validation rules
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full name', 'trim|required');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('designation', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {   
                $data['main_content']   =   'staff/add_staff';
                $this->load->view('admin/template',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/staff/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';


                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
                {
                                            $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $new_staff = array(
                            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                            'designation' => $this->input->post('designation'),
                                                            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                                                            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                                                            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                                                            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                            'status' => $this->input->post('status')
                    );

                }
                else
                {   
                    $file_data  =   $this->upload->data('file');

                    $new_staff = array(
                            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                            'designation' => $this->input->post('designation'),
                                                            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                                                            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                                                            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                                                            'photo' => $file_data['file_name'],
                                                            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                            'status' => $this->input->post('status')
                    );

                }                   
                    if($this->staff_model->add_staff($new_staff)):
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Staff added Sucessfully !!');
                    endif;
                    redirect('admin/staff');                        
            }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry sujeet, but what's the purpose of this code? It is really unclear in what purpose it serves (am also new to CI)

Comment: (1) redirect to form if not isset($_POST)
(2) if isset($_POST) and meets validation, uploads files and call model to insert into db.

works for add and edit form with images. Replace image if image is provided while edit. if not use current image

Answer (score 0):

you can pass in other data as well along with file form your form to controller, like

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
    <input type="text" name="someField" value=""  />
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

and in your **upload** controller's **do_upload** function:

```
$someField = $this->input->post("somefield"); //save to some db
//and rest of your file to be uploaded code from the same link you provided
```

Did you mean something like this

Comment: will this work? Because there is a whole example on uploading file where I can check for type of images and all. So should I pass $somefield to that method and that's it?

Answer (score 0):

Image MOO is a excellent library that can accomplish image manipulations on the fly....

e.g for resizing the uploaded image to a particular path, you just have to do this

```
public function thumbnailer($uploader_response,$field_info,$files_to_upload)
{
    $this->load->library('image_moo');
$file_uploaded=$field_info->upload_path.'/'.$uploader_response[0]->name;
$thumbnails=$field_info->upload_path.'/thumbnails/'.$uploader_response[0]->name;
    $cart_thumbnails=$field_info->upload_path.'/cart_thumbnails/'.$uploader_response[0]->name;
$this->image_moo->load($file_uploaded)->resize(400,250)->save($thumbnails,false);
}
```

Hope this helps !!