# How to store and retrieve image from DATABASE in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to ci. I have seen the documentation for file uploader and 
implemented the sample page. But I want to upload the image and store it into MySQL database.
Can anyone provide solution for it with example?

Comment: Here is an example: [http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-file-upload](http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-file-upload) You can also refer to this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345862/codeigniter-upload-image-with-other-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345862/codeigniter-upload-image-with-other-data)

Answer (score 0):

Upload the image to a folder called uploads and then store the path to the image in your DB